# Aggregator and Forwarder

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any single word for something who "aggregate and forward"?
I have a program which collect logs from all machines and then forwards/feeds it to various other components. I want to name this program :).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because naming, especially naming programming object, is explicitly off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is called [*store and forward*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Store_and_forward) (Wikipedia).